# Custom error pages in Spring Boot 1.4 not picked up when using JSP resolver

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot, error-handling

I am trying to use my own custom error pages in my Spring Boot 1.4 application. According to documentation, it should be sufficient to place my error pages in `src/main/resources/public/error` directory (for, example `404.html`).

However, I am also using JSP pages in my application and have a resolver for them:

```
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(final ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    final UrlBasedViewResolverRegistration resolver = registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/jsp/", ".jsp");

    final Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    attributes.put("HASH", hashReader.getHashValue());
    attributes.put("Hoker", hookerReader.getHooker());
    resolver.attributes(attributes);
}
```

Whenever I experience an `4xx` error, instead of using the custom error page I put in the `resources/public/error` directory, it tries to load `/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp`.

Is there a way how to force Spring Boot to use its default behavior instead of trying to resolve the error pages to the JSP directory?

Comment: This actually is the default behavior... It tries to resolve to a view named `404` (or whatever depending on the error code). That is passed to your view resolver which doesn't have one (but as it is a Url based version always returns a URL). Redirecting fails, which in turn will lead to trying to resolve a view named `error` which in turn is passed to your view resolver again.

Comment: But I  had a view name in resources/public/error/404.html. But it was being ignored

Comment: Correct. That is what I explained... `404` is the view name, which is passed to your `ViewResolver`, which tries to resolve a view on `/WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp`. The default behavior is actually that. Normally when no `UrlBasedViewResolver` is registered it will eventually pass on to the default static resource handling. But due to a `UrlBasedViewResolver` being present that is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example, https://github.com/lenicliu/eg-spring/tree/master/eg-spring-boot/eg-spring-boot-webmvc

i guess u could fix it like this:

```
package com.lenicliu.spring.boot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ErrorPage;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer customizeContainerr() {
        return new CustomizedContainer();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    private static class CustomizedContainer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404.html"));
            container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/500.html"));
        }
    }
}
```

and u could put 404.html and 500.html into following folders:

```
src/main/resource/static/500.html
src/main/resource/static/404.html
```

**OR** like this:

```
container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/error/404.html"));
container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/error/500.html"));
```

and then put them into

```
src/main/resource/static/error/500.html
src/main/resource/static/error/404.html
```

reference to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

/static or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources, them are same.

hope to help u :)